# django get queryset of a object with chained foreign key

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship

I have a project which looks like:

```
mysite/
|-- books
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- models.py
`-- org
    |-- __init__.py
    `-- models.py
```

books/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

from mysite.org.models import Team

class BookSet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='booksets')

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    book_set = models.ForeignKey(BookSet, related_name='books')
```

org/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, related_name='teams')
```

What I want to achieve is getting all books for a Department, something similar to:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    @property
    def books(self):
        # this won't work, is there any possible do it like this?
        return self.teams.booksets.books()
```

I know one possible method is doing it via:

```
from mysite.books.models import Book

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    @property
    def books(self):
        return Book.objects.filter(book_set__team__department=self)
```

But with this method, I need to do something tricky to allow them (books.models and org.models) to import each other cyclically.

So I'm wondering whether it's possible to find out all the Books for a Department by querying with the foreign key, which is something like:

```
    @property
    def books(self):
        # this won't work, is there any possible do it like this?
        return self.teams.booksets.books()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to avoid the cyclical import is by making your your `Department` model like so:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    @property
    def books(self):
        from mysite.books.models import Book
        return Book.objects.filter(book_set__team__department=self)
```

Comment: at least an easy solution for cyclical importing :)

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this would work:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    @property
    def books(self):
        booksets = list(team.booksets.all() for team in self.teams.all())
        return list(bookset.books.all() for bookset in booksets)
```

But I don't have an easy way to test it.

Edit: An alternative I forgot to add:

You can use strings to refer to models in ForeignKey definitions. like so:

```
class BookSet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    team = models.ForeignKey('org.Team', related_name='booksets')
```

Then in you're other application you can freely import books.models

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) for more info.

Comment: I'm afraid this may cause performance issue when the data size grows too large, not sure.

Comment: It most likely would, yes. But what you're doing is basically a JOIN across several tables.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the same mechanism that Django uses to load Foreign Keys like

`user = models.ForeignKey('User')`

How do to that:

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model
Book = get_model('books', 'Book')

# which would achieve the same thing as
# from books.models import Book
```

`get_model` is defined as:

`def get_model(self, app_label, model_name, seed_cache=True):
  ...`